# Redirect to a specific section from a different page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I redirect from a different page to a page that has hidden sections which can only be visible once they are clicked?

I have two pages. One page has 4 full viewheight sections (3 hidden at all times) and other is just a page with content. The former page has a sidebar that makes the sections visible on click. I want to redirect from the second (content) page to one of those sections but I feel the I am unable to as that section on the first page needs to be clicked in order to make active.

```
//Function for switching tabs on the first page
var navigate = function(e) {
        var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');        
        // Show/Hide Tabs
        $(currentAttrValue).addClass('active').fadeIn().siblings().hide().removeClass('active');
        // // Change/remove current tab to active
        $(this).addClass('highlighted').siblings().removeClass('highlighted');
        e.preventDefault();
}
```

The section I am trying to access has a 'display:none' property by default. I am looking for something that upon clicking from the source page makes the 'display: active' for the particular section on the target page and redirects. Sorry if I didn't frame my question better earlier.

Comment: This code itself means nothing.

Comment: Assuming you have full authorship capabilities on both pages you could read a URL param when your target page is loaded.  From your source page, pass that URL parameter in the hyperlink to trigger the section to open in your target page.

Answer (score 0):

Branching directly off Marc's comment, you can get a pretty good idea of how to get the URL parameter from this question:
[Get url parameter jquery Or How to Get Query String Values In js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery-or-how-to-get-query-string-values-in-js)

In the linked answer, a function is created to get the URL param. The idea would be, in the first page, to add the parameter directly in the link to the second page. I will assume that the page 1 link looks like:

```
https://www.your-site.com/page1?section=2
```

With the *getUrlParameter* function in the second page you could do something like:

```
var sectionToOpen = getUrlParameter('section');
```

Once you got the value, you can do your whatever condition is required to open up the specific sections.

Comment: Hi Cesar, thanks for the answer. I tried this but it didn't work. The section I am trying to access has a 'display:none' property by default. I am looking for something that upon clicking from the source page makes the display: active for the particular section on the target page and redirects. Sorry if I didn't frame my question better earlier.